# Modification required for the perl command

Tags: files, perl, aix

I need a modification for the below perl command:

```
perl -wE 'say for ((sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } </tmp/?>)[0..9]);'
```

Requirement:

1. It should scan through all the sub-directories inside the target directory.
2. List down the top 10 files with their size and path.

Answer (score 2):

Use [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find) to recursively walk the directory tree:

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE '
    find(sub { push @all, $File::Find::name }, "/tmp");
    say for (sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } @all)[0..9]'
```

If there are too many files and you're getting `Out of memory`, return the sizes and use external `sort` and `head` to limit the output:

```
perl -MFile::Find -wE 'find(sub { say -s $_, " $File::Find::name" }, "/tmp")' \
| sort -nr | head -n10
```

Comment: thanks for the response. 
I got the file names, how can i get the size of the files too along with the file names.

Comment: add `| xargs du -h` to the above perl command output

Comment: I found this for the file size: https://perlmaven.com/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-perl

Comment: i see the size details came out are different with the perl command and with the unix find command

Comment: hpauto@st2ba1301:/tmp$ p"); say for (sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } @all)[0..9]' 2>/dev/null | xargs du -s                                                                 <



343800  /tmp/Spectra/spectre_meltdown_fix.tar
38336   /tmp/lftp_latest/gcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm

Comment: hpauto@st2ba1301:/tmp$ find /tmp -type f -print 2>/dev/null | xargs ls -l 2>/dev/null | sort -k5,5rn | head -10 | awk '{print$5,$9}'


176025600 /tmp/Spectra/spectre_meltdown_fix.tar
19624929 /tmp/lftp_latest/gcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm

Comment: also when i run on bigger filesystems it gave a message "Out of Memory" :(

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR: Check the update.

Comment: Output:

Out of memory

6607422427 /opt/app/DataStage/IS_11.3.1_AIX_ML.tar.gz
6580611963 /opt/app/DataStage/INFO_IS_11.3_AIX_ML.tar.gz
4267159871 /opt/app/DataStage/is-suite.is_11_3_1.aix64.GA.141024.part2.tar.gz
2340294124 /opt/app/DataStage/is-suite.is_11_3_1.aix64.GA.141024.part1.tar.gz
2141922298 /opt/app/DataStage/InfoSvr_Client_v8.7_Win.zip
1546065920 /opt/app/DSPRD/DS_PROD.tar
660123648 /opt/app/CPP/xlcpp.12.1.0.aix.GM.tar
470921216 /opt/app/InformationServer/Server/DSOMD/xml

Comment: Output from the find command (but takes 15 mins to scan and sort my larger file systems)

10344988672 /opt/app/InformationServer/Server/Datasets/ITEM_LOC_SOH.ds.dsadm.dstageservsvc.0000.0000.0000.25a009a.5aff724e.0000.e559a832
10344988672 /opt/app/InformationServer/Server/Datasets/ITEM_LOC_SOH.ds.dsadm.dstageservsvc.0000.0001.0000.25a009a.5aff724e.0001.849b16ef
10344988672 /opt/app/InformationServer/Server/Datasets/ITEM_LOC_SOH.ds.dsadm.dstageservsvc.0000.0002.0000.25a009a.5aff724e.0002.0975947a

Comment: @choroba, the command you suggested worked good and was way faster than find command, however there was an Out of Memory message and output was different.

In the find command, im getting the larger files, but the execution time is too high.

Comment: @choroba, shall i try re-directing the output to a file and then process.. may be out of memory error would disappear....!!

Comment: @choroba.. any suggestions?

Comment: Hou much memory do you have? How many files do you have, how deep is the directory structure?

Answer (score 2):

This perl script will print exactly what you need, it is using `File::Find` to traverse recursively.
I have used `-f` to make sure only files are pushed into the hash

Hash `%files` has `filepath` as the key and `size` as its value. Then sorted it on basis of values and printed the top 10 results

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my %files;
my $counter=0;
find( \&wanted, '<target directory>');
for my $file  ( sort {$files{$b} <=> $files{$a}}  keys%files){
        print "$file : $files{$file}\n";
        $counter++;
        if ($counter == 10){
                last;
        }
}


sub wanted {
  $files{"$File::Find::name"}=-s $File::Find::name if -f;
  return;

}
```

Or  simply using an array to get it working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;
my $counter=0;
find( \&wanted, '<target directory>');
for my $file  ( sort { -s $b <=> -s $a}  @files){
        my $size = -s $file;
        print "$file : $size\n"
        $counter++;
        if ($counter == 10){
                last;
}
sub wanted{
  push @files,$File::Find::name if -f;
  return;
}
```

Comment: in your above code second snippet `@files[0..9]`  won't give top sorted file names , but will only run sort on first 10 entries of `@files` array

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestion, i have edited my answer to get the correct result

Comment: it worked charm for my lower size directories. 
However for a bigger size, im getting an "Out of Memory" message

Comment: @Arushix... any suggestion to avoid the Out of Memory message?

Answer (score 1):

```
zsh -c 'ls -ldS /tmp/**/?(DOL[1,10])'
```

To `l`i`s`t the `10` `L`argest single-character (`?`) files in `/tmp` and subdirs (`**/`), ordered by `S`ize.

With `perl`, and to avoid storing the whole file list in memory when you only want the 10 largest ones:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e '
  find(
    sub {
      if (length == 1 && $_ ne ".") {
        @s = sort {$b->[0] <=> $a->[0]} [-s, $File::Find::name], @s;
        splice @s, 10
      }
    }, "/tmp"
  ); printf "%16d %s\n", @{$_} for @s'
```

(the `length == 1 && $_ ne "."` is to match on single-byte file names like your `/tmp/?` suggests you want to do).

Instead of `printf "%16d %s\n", @{$_}`, you could also run `ls` like in the `zsh` solution with `exec "ls", "-ldS", map $_->[1], @s`

Comment: doesnt have zsh utility...it doesnt work 4 me

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR, most Unix-like systems have `zsh` available as a package.

Comment: i tried to run this, it dint work. Mine is AIX.

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR, again, you'd need to install it first. Even IBM apparently provides zsh packages these days for AIX. Anyway, I've added a `perl` solution.

Comment: [link to IBM AIX Toolbox for Linux](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html) and [directly to the zsh rpm](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/zsh/zsh-4.0.4-3.aix5.1.ppc.rpm)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, i cannot installe that package, due to client restrictions. However I have tried the perl solution.  

I have deleted the if condition and ran, the output was fine. But when it came to larger filesystem with very huge amount of files it ended up in "Out of Memory" error....!!  :(

Answer (score 0):

easier with bash I would say

`find ${PATH_TO_PARENT_FOLDER} -type f -exec du -ahx {} + | sort -rh | head -10`

Essentially we are using `find` to locate all files inside a folder,

- `-type` either `f` for file or `d` for dir
- `-exec` executes a command using the output of find and places find result as argument at `{}`

then executing `du` to calculate the size of each element found through find and adding

- `-a, --all`  write counts for all files, not just directories
- `-h, --human-readable`  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
- `-x, --one-file-system`  skip directories on different file systems

Then we pipe it to sort it form bigger to smaller and we use head to present the top 10 only

`sort` to sort the output result

- `-h, --human-numeric-sort`  compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
- `-r, --reverse`  reverse the result of comparisons

`head` to just read the top results

- `-<N>` to set the amount of lines you want to see from 1 to N

Comment: I have a directory with more than 300000 files, find command takes around 15mins or it goes in hung state.. !! :(

Comment: you could combine the solution from @choroba with mine, read the FS using perl, then apply for each of the found results the commands I shared with you :)

Comment: choroba's command is failing with "Out of memory"

Comment: ??????????????????